# can't login Kali 2.0 after fresh installation

Tags: kali-linux

Installed new instance of Kali 2.0 graphical in Virtualbox. Created a normal user say "user1" and set the Password of root as "pass123".
After installation (no error encountered), tried login into Kali 2.0 using normal user "user1", can't get in and received "wrong password" related error.
Then, tried using root user and password "user1" (was set during installation); user root is not recognized in the login window and same only User login window just bounces back

Comment: The answer below is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

When you login to `kali` you need to use username root and password that you used during installation.

In live mode, or any other mode. default username is `root` and password is `toor`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below steps to recover the root password what I set during installation.

1. restart Kali Linux after the installation
2. select option "*Advanced options for kali GNU/Linux"
3. then select option "Kali GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 (recovery mode)" 
   Note: I am using x64 bit machine for i386 you might see related machine type
4. enter the root password (the one you had set during installation) for the recovery and you get the root prompt. that's it :-)
5. type " init 6" and hit enter key to restart Kali 2.0
6. after reboot the user "root" and associated password just works

I am not sure if one of the above is an standard way to solve this problem. However, it unlocked me without making any additional changes into the system and allowed me to use the same password that was set during Kali installation